# Рандом число с увеличением шанса при неудаче Java

Tags: java, случайные-числа, теория-вероятностей

Сегодня задался вопросом. Допустим есть числа от 1 до 5.
У каждого числа шанс выпадения разный. Допустим 
1 = 10%
2 = 15%
3 = 20%
4 = 25%
5 = 30%.
Но если именно не падает число 1, то его шанс выпадения увеличивается на 1%(шансы других не меняются)
И посчитать количество выпадений разных чисел ща n- итерацию.
Я думал по поводу простого увеличения массива.
Например рандомно генерируем число 1-100
и если выпало бы 1-10  -число 1
11-25  -число 2 и т.д
А до тех пор пока число 1 не выпадет, увеличивать массив на единицу 100+1.
падает 1-11  -число 1
12-26 -число 2 и т.д.
Но можно ли как-то по другому реализовать это?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: `Но если именно не падает число 1, то его шанс выпадения увеличивается на 1%(шансы других не меняются)` вы берете монетку,  шанс выпадения каждой стороны 50%/50%. Если выпала решка, шанс орла увеличиваем вдвое. Вопрос - можем мы оставить шанс выпадения решки 50%, если шанс орла будет 100%?

Comment: @tym32167 а теперь другая ситуация(которую описывает автор, и шанс реально не меняется): у нас есть кладовка. в кладовке с шансом 50% есть вилосипед, с шансом 30% есть банка варенья... если сегодня заглянули и банки варенья небыло - завтра шанс найти ее в кладовке - увеличится(жена притащит например).... а вот велосипед если нашелся - так и будет 50%(жена может уехать на нем и он будет либо нет и его не будет :) с тем же шансом 50% как и в прошлый день)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков это работает если шансы не взаимоисключающие, например, если можно найти в кладовке и велосипед и варенье разом. Но это не то, что описал автор. У автора, если выпало 1- это означает, что все остальные не выпали. А значит, сумма всех вероятностей должна быть 100%, и если где то вероятность увеличивается, то где то соответственно уменьшается.

Comment: @tym32167
Не обязательно и даже в случае с как вы говорите с выпадением одного числа, если шанс выпадения любого числа не 100% (т.е. сумма шансов меньше 100% ;)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков ну так это не случай автора, сумма его шансов 100%, посчитайте сами.

Comment: Новые вероятности в вашем случае не будут увеличиваться на 1%: 11/101 = 10,89%, 12/102 = 11,76%, 13/103 = 12,62% ... 20/110 = 18,18% (не 20%), соответственно будут изменяться и вероятности других выпадений.

Comment: http://mathprofi.ru/teorija_verojatnostei.html Кстати, если не выпадает 2 - тоже вероятности поднимать?